# upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 aborted using graphical package manager

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

Thinkpad 64bit running 18.04.5 up to date
Update mamager prompted to upgrade to 20.04 lts
Got an error message early on "new libre-office-common package pre-install script subprocess returned error exit status 1"
After I closed the error message, the upgrade seemed to proceed and then
"Upgrade aborted"
Version of ubuntu still says 18.04.5
LibreOffice apps don't run
Other apps that I use regularly seem ok so far.
Is there a log of the data that streams across during the upgrade process?
I have a warning symbol that says "Error: broken count >0"  usually means that your installed packages have missing dependencies.
How do I find and install the missing dependencies?

EDIT: Libreoffice issue is now resolved.  Ran apt-get check which located all the problems in libreoffice and then ran apt --fix-broken install.  That installed LibreOffice 7, the office apps work, and the warning symbol about broken links is gone after reboot.

However, we are still at 18.04.5.  Should I try to upgrade to 20.04 again?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try to upgrade to 20.04 again after getting LibreOffice fixed.  Decided to use the command line instead of the gui software manager after reading several articles about the 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade.  After a backup, I ran apt-get update and then apt-get upgrade.  Rebooted.  Ran apt-get install update-manager-core; it was already at the newest version.  Then do-release-upgrade.  This ran quite awhile as expected and appears to have completed successfully.  I am now on 20.04.1.  Have experienced no software issues so far.  Looks like I'm starting the new year with a new os.